# Unable to transform web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web.config-transform

I have just started using web.config transformation and I am able to apply successfully replace transformation. however I am struggling with little more complex transformation such as

```
<downloadHandlers>
  <add name="FileDownload" path="~/Download.ashx">
    <tcpDownloadEndpoint endpointIPAddress="127.0.0.1" endpointPort="8100" />
  </add>
</downloadHandlers>
```

I have the following line in the transformation file to replace the local IP with UAT IP  for UAT env.

```
<tcpDownloadEndpoint 
endpointIPAddress="127.127.0.1"
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(endpointIPAddress)">
</tcpDownloadEndpoint >
```

But the above code has no effect and the IP in the web.config still contains the local IP after transformation.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with web.config transformation plugin written by Syed Hashmi (MS).

Can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following in your transformation web.config:

```
<downloadHandlers>
  <add name="FileDownload" path="~/Download.ashx">
    <tcpDownloadEndpoint
  endpointIPAddress="127.127.0.1"
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(endpointIPAddress)">
    </tcpDownloadEndpoint >
  </add>
</downloadHandlers>
```

You need to use the complete XML node hierarchy when specifying a transform. By removing the outer nodes, the web.config transformation can't find the exact node that you want to transform.

Comment: Thanks @Wouter but this didn't have any effect on it either :( the value is still 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.127.0.1.

Comment: How are you viewing the results? Where do you put the transformation?

Comment: I am previewing the result in Visual Studio by right clicking on Web.SIT.Config file and selecting Preview Transform.

Comment: apologies I missed one more parent node <filehandlers> and hence the transformation engine was unable to find the element at the specified location just like you suggested. Marking your answer as the right answer. Thanks a bunch